# Why does the size of div decrease on adding a horizontal scrollbar in CSS of React project?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, scrollbar

Please refer to this image. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZvQP.png)

The cards in both the lists are of same dimensions. But in the second list, I have enabled scrolling. On enabling it, the dimensions suddenly changes and the things become clumsy.

I am attaching the source code:

```
const cast_lists = this.state.cast.map(ar =>{
            return(
                    <Card style={{ width: 120, height : 230, borderColor : "black", borderWidth: 1, borderStyle : "solid", marginLeft: 5, position: "relative"}}>
                <Card.Img variant="top" src={"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + ar.profile_path} style = {{height: 150, width: 120, marginLeft: -60, borderColor : "black", borderWidth: 10, position: "relative"}} />
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title style = {{paddingTop: 150, paddingLeft: 0, fontWeight: "bold"}}> {ar.name} </Card.Title>
                    <Card.Body>{ar.character}</Card.Body>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
            )
        })
```

In return of render, the code is:

```
<div  className = {styles.top}>
                   <h2>Top Crew</h2>
                   <div style = {{display: "flex", flexDirection : "row", overflow: "auto"}}>
                   {crew_lists.slice(0,5)}
                   </div> 
                   <h2>Top Crew</h2>
                   <div style = {{display: "flex", flexDirection : "row", overflowX: "scroll", width: 500}}>
                   {cast_lists}
                   </div>    
            </div>
```

The styles.top sets the height and width to 100%.
Please help me in mending this.

EDIT:
On removing the second width, the horizontal scrollbar disappears. Also the above components gets distorted. Attaching the screenshot
[image]

Comment: can you send me url of your web? Or atleast what Card component did you use?

Comment: @development-ninja Hi. I have used Card component of React Bootstrap. I have also made some changes in style as you can see.

Comment: Can you send me your web url? I have not installed react-bootstrap on myside. You can send me in private if you dont want it public

Comment: Can you paste here full code here? i have just installed bootstrap

Comment: did you fix this issue already?

Comment: can you please let me know your feedback

Answer (score 0):

have you tried removing `width: 500` from the second `div`

Comment: I have edited the question and added the required screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You should insert min-width property to your style of Card component

```
<Card style={{ width: 120, height : 230, minWidth:120, borderColor : "black", borderWidth: 1, borderStyle : "solid", marginLeft: 5, position: "relative"}}>
```

So I added `minWidth` property to Card style.
Hope it works.

Comment: @abc did you try my answer? Please want feedback on my answer))

Comment: @abc please let me know your feedback.